# IE8 on Win7 image not loaded

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have an image that is not loading in IE8.  When browsing to the image it comes up. It loads in Firefox and Chrome.

I have tried running IE8 in safe mode and compatibility mode.

On some boxes with the same OS and browser it displays.  Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are they static images?  What do the URLs look like for the images?

Comment: would you mind to share your code and/or create an example on http://jsfiddle.net ..? :)

Answer (score 0):

Cant see your code but I've had this problem before.

Im guessing you've got

```
<img src="pathtoimage/photo.jpg">
```

Try

```
<img src="/pathtoimage/photo.jpg" />
```

or try substituting in an absolute url and see if it makes a difference

```
<img src="http://mysite/pathtoimage/myphoto.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you see? A red-X? I have seen this happen with some .jpg's with funky color settings. I apologize for not knowing the exact specifics, but I sent it back to our graphics folks who know immediately what to do. "Oh, sorry - wrong blahblah. Try this one." and it works. CMYK vs. RGB maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the AlphaImageLoader IE hack to get transparency.  Our image is a gif with the css AlphaImageLoader style applied.